# Argument resolution specific to NULL

Tags: c++

C++11 introduced `std::nullptr_t` to allow explicit overloading of methods where the `nullptr` constant is passed. What I'd like is the same thing but with the old `NULL` (aka 0).
I feel like there should be a solution maybe leveraging SFINAE but for the life of me I can't think of one.

To be even more clear I would like to have 3 methods:

```
Foo(int*); //binds to an int pointer
Foo(std::nullptr_t); //binds to a nullptr constant
Foo(something); //should bind to NULL
```

What should `something` be so that a call to `Foo(NULL)` would not be ambiguous?

I wouldn't want the method overload for NULL to bind to arbitrary integers

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not think it is possible. An overload can only be done based on type, and NULL is just not a specific type. SFINAE won't help here either.

Comment: but the type of NULL is known (decltype(NULL)). I wonder if I can resolve based on a constexpr value of that type

Comment: @IlBeldus No its not. Its not `#define NULL (int)0`. It is just `#define NULL 0`. `0` has no type, it depends in which context it is used. And when it is substituded by the pre-processor in this case there is no way to tell what type it is because 0 can implicitly convert to both.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox strictly speaking, this is not correct. First of, `0`, of course, has a type, as any other literal. It's type is `int`. Second, NULL can be anything, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL. It can be `void*(0)`, or plain 0, or something else. In CLang, for example, it is built-in `__null`, so likely to be the same as `nullptr`. All this ambiguity makes overloading on nullptr impossible.  For example, on implementations which use 0L as `NULL`, you can catch it in `foo(long int)` - but of course, it will accept any long int.

Comment: Re: "for the life of me I can't think of one" -- that's why `nullptr` was introduced. <g>

Comment: @SergeyA you linked C NULL. The C++ NULL is defined differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `Foo(std::nullptr_t)` overload will work with `NULL` too. There's an implicit conversion from *any* null pointer constant to `std::nullptr_t`. That includes `0`, `0UL`, whatever `NULL` is defined as, and of course `nullptr` itself.

If your only wish to disambiguate the `int*` from `nullptr_t`, then we can just tinker with the rules of overload resolution. For instance, make `Foo(int*)` a template:

```
template<int = 0>
void Foo(int*); 
void Foo(std::nullptr_t);
```

A non-template is always a better match to to a template when overloading.

Comment: Yes but calling Foo(NULL) is ambiguous as it can bind to both int* and nullptr. i want to solve the ambiguity

Comment: @IlBeldus - Disambiguation is also possible. Though now it's less pretty.

Comment: "less pretty"? Call it for what it is. That's ugly :D.

Comment: @CássioRenan - Have you ever seen a C++ library not chalk full of ugliness? So long as user code can be oblivious to it and simply write `foo(/*whatever*/)` with expected semantics, we can be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

> C++11 introduced std::nullptr_t to allow explicit overloading of methods where the nullptr constant is passed.

Not exactly. It was introduced so you can have a type-safe *null*. This doesn't work the way you expect:

```
foo (int a);
foo (int *a);
...
foo (NULL); // Calls the overload with `int` not `int*`!
```

What is the point of this function:

```
Foo(std::nullptr_t a);
```

It couldn't possibly do anything useful that `Foo()` couldn't do. In your example, passing `NULL`, shouldn't be the concern. You should be considering why you are not using `#define NULL nullptr`. Or just using `nullptr` directly.

To answer the overall question: **Argument resolution specific to NULL**

I don't think this is possible. NULL is not a specific type, you can't use type detection methods to choose the correct overload.

Comment: Sorry, bigger picture: I have Foo(int*); and Foo(const int*); that do 2 different things. Now I want to solve my compiler shouting at me if I call Foo(nullptr) or Foo(NULL)

Comment: @IlBeldus Then why didn't you just ask that question?